# iOS assure viewcontroller transition ended

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I've a bunch of turn based games in my app, and I use the same animations to declare the starting player.

At the very end of viewDidLoad, I placed the code for declaration. It takes the screenshot of current view then blurs it a little, and labels appear to show the name of the starting player. The issue is sometimes it happens to fast that I got the screenshot of previous view and labels appear on the blurred screenshot of previous view.

My viewDidLoad looks like this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initializeThings];

    [self layoutUI]; //In some of the games this part requires heavy processing,
                     //ie laying out a 2D array of buttons (20x20=400 of them)

    [self showStartingPlayer];
}
```

I use the default transition style `cover vertical` in all VCs. I tried calling `[self showStartingPlayer];` deferred by using performSelector with delay but different devices require different delay values so it is not a robust solution. Is there any other method I can use in viewcontroller lifecycle instead of viewDidLoad or any practical way of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called when the view of the view controller has been loaded, but it doesn't mean that it's actually visible on the screen.

You may use `- (void) viewDidAppear:` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `presentViewController: animated: completion:`, i would take advantage of the completion block to notify the view controller that the transition is complete.

for example, you could add a public method called `-(void)wasJustPresented` to your view controller which calls the necessary UI layout.

Then, call this in your completion block. Ex:

```
[self presentViewController:newVC
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^(void){
            [newVC wasJustPresented];
            }];
```

This will ensure your view controller is notified right after it is done being presented.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to call your method inside the `viewDidAppear` which is called as the view transition has finished.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //put your call here
}
```